# IIS7 Asp.net - the compilation is very slow

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm working with iis7 asp.net project.
when updating: .bin, .config, and app code the iis compile the site.
the comppilaton process took very long time.

what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, starting an ASP.NET application in IIS is relatively slow.

The solution is "Application Initialization". This is built-in in IIS 8 and available out-of-band as a module for IIS 7.5,7.0,8.0: . Check this link for information: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization